# Loading images using Glide in Imageview

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I am using Glide library for loading images in imageview and using the below code.

```
Glide.with(mActivity)
                .load(img.getmGridViewImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.color.grey_light)
                .into(imageHolder.imageView);
```

The placeholder with grey color gets visible until the image does not load but after the image get loads in imageview, the placeholder still take place and show some blank space after that image.

How can I resolve this issue. Please help me if you have any idea here.

Comment: are u sure u are not setting background to imageview in xml

Comment: No I am not using any background to the imageview in xm file. 
`<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`
This is what I am using for imageView.

Comment: try removing scaleType or adjustViewBounds , are u sure u need this 2 property

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

When I give fix height to the `ImageView` it works for me.

Here's the layout

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgPoster"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_of_getInspired_list"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" 
    android:src="@drawable/default_image"/>
```

Here's my code.

```
Glide.with(this.context).load(inspiredList.get(position).image)
.error(R.drawable.default_image)
.centerCrop()
.crossFade()
.placeholder(R.drawable.default_image).into(holder.imgPoster);
```

Comment: I can not give the fix image height to imageview, I have to give wrap_content only to the imageview.

Comment: you can also try Picasso which is similar to Glide.
http://square.github.io/picasso/
Glide library have a problem with some .jpeg file it becomes green colour or grey colour background. Please verify it with .png files.

Also check the scale type FitXy it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. This will help you..

```
Glide.with(this).load(photo_url)
            .crossFade()
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.plaeholder_image)
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(imageView);
```

Please use placeholder image instead of color. you will able to use plain grey color image from drawable for placeholder image.