# Glide can't load file from internal storage

Tags: android, android-glide

I have an `Activity` in which I download a zipfile of images and then unzip in the `getFilesDir()`. Path is like this :

> /data/user/0/packagename/files/files/example.png

When I try to load these images however, they're not showing. 
I'm using this code to get the path and load the image:

```
   String loc = getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + Config.IMAGES_LOCATION +"/";
   String imageloc = loc + model.getThumbnail();
   Glide.with(ActivityImageGallery.this).load(imageloc).into(image);
```

The imageloc path is the same as the save location and when creating a file from the path, it shows that it would exist.

I tried using `file://` in front of the path, but that doesn't work either. `WRITE_EXTERNAL` en `READ_EXTERNAL` permissions are asked and granted.

Comment: Are you testing on android N?

Comment: No on my Oneplus 2 running Android 6.0

Comment: did you try using loading listener of glide using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42067675/5492047 and check the exception ? and awesome tutorial can be found here in depth https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started.

Comment: What if `model.getThumbnail()` is null ?

Comment: What is the log output of `loc` and `imageloc`?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: do you still need help?

Comment: will try everything this afternoon, been very busy sorry

Comment: Probably the images are very large that the some devices can't load. Why don't you try with some small images?

Answer (score 18):

This works for me, make file instance and pass file's uri that you want to load into `ImageView`

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(new File(fileUri.getPath())) // Uri of the picture
    .into(profileAvatar);
```

Make sure you have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You can also use `RequestListener` to trace the error in case of failure

```
new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

First capture your image path,either you are capturing image from camera or picking it from gallery(I assume you have already given read and write permissions). Then Try this

```
Glide.with(context).load(new File(imagePath)).dontAnimate().error(R.drawable.errorImage).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholderImage).into(imageView);
```

Using `.dontAnimate()` because in some case it may be that image did not load or show when you load first time(or take extra time).
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using loading listener of glide using this

**1.Debug:-**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42067675/5492047

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
 .load(args.getString(IMAGE_TO_SHOW))
 .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
     @Override
     public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

         return false;
     }
 })
 .into(imageFrame);
```

and check the exception ?

**2.Debug Again.**

Can you use any file explorer app and go to the exact place where the file is loaded and open then file?.

**3.Path**

Is it really /files/files/ in the path?

4.Extension
Can you remove .png from the file path and load and check?

**5.Tutorial**

An awesome tutorial can be found here in depth https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
File c = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/user/0/packagename/files/files/example.png");
Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(c).error(R.drawable.empty_pic).placeholder(R.drawable.empty_pic).into(image2);
```

or try this

```
 Glide.with(getActivity()).load(new File(" your path").toString())
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                Log.e("xmx1","Error "+e.toString());
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                Log.e("xmx1","no Error ");
                return false;
            }
        })
        .into(ivx);
```

Comment: i am getting images camera and gallery both can you please tell me which where i can get perfect path and set it in to glide for now i only see my place holder 
path= /storage/emulated/0/1586779115967.jpg like this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need run time permissions to use internal storage.Second use latest glide library 
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
and format as

```
Glide.with(context).load(image path).into(Imageview);
```